# Computing an integral numerically

Tags: numerical-integration, special-functions

```
P = 0;
l = 0;
x = 4;
κ = 0.01;
n = 5;
q = (κ*n)/2;

Do[Q = (Exp[((-I)*(MathieuCharacteristicA[ν, q] - x^2/4)*(τ/2))])*
       (Integrate[
         (Exp[(-I)*(l - x/2)*(θ)])*(Exp[(I)*(ν)*(θ)])*
         (MathieuC[MathieuCharacteristicA[ν, q], q, θ]),
         {θ, 0, 2 π}
        ])*
       (Integrate[
         (Exp[(I)*(y - x/2)*(z)])*(Exp[(-I)*(ν)*(z)])*
         (MathieuC[MathieuCharacteristicA[ν, q], q, z]),
         {z, 0, 2 π}
        ]);
  P = P + Q, 
  {y, 0, 8, 2}, {ν, 6, 14, 2}
];

Q1 = N[P]
```

I get error when I get numerical value. But there is no error until value of y is in range 0 to 6. As it increases from 6 to 8, I get the error. When I tried max recurssion limit of 12, I see a "not machine sized integer" error.

Please help.

Comment: Please format your code and question to make it more readable. Help on editing can be found using the button on the top right of the edit box.

Comment: is it ok now?
Actually i am new and i m too much confused :(

Comment: I formatted your code. Please take note of how it should be, because your complicated expression was a real nuisance to indent properly, especially given how many extraneous parentheses you have. You are doing numerical integration completely wrongly. You should use `NIntegrate`. Additionally primed symbols mean derivatives in *Mathematica*, so you should get rid of those.

Comment: There are problems with MathieuC, not sure if [related](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/83032/is-mathieuc-for-moderately-large-imaginary-arguments-broken#comment225641_83032)

Comment: primed symbol is just to differentiate otherwise these are not derivatives

Comment: MathieuC is related

Comment: Giving l the value zero and then differentiating does not do anything useful here. Using a differentiated symbol as a dummy variable of integration is likely perilous as well. In any case, you haven't told Mathematica what the independent variable for the derivative is, so your derivatives are meaningless.

Comment: the issue is not with derivative, even if for l' i use another dummy variable and  increase value from 6 to 8 it gives error

Comment: l = 0; x = 4; \\[Kappa] = 1/100; n = 5; q = (\\[Kappa]*n)/2; Total[ Flatten[ Table[ N[Exp[-I*(MathieuCharacteristicA[\\[Nu], q] - x^2/4)*\\[Tau]/2]* Integrate[ Exp[-I*(l - x/2)*\\[Theta]]*Exp[I*\\[Nu]*\\[Theta]]* MathieuC[MathieuCharacteristicA[\\[Nu], q], q, \\[Theta]], {\\[Theta], 0, 2 Pi}]* Integrate[ Exp[I*(y - x/2)*z]*Exp[-I*\\[Nu]*z]* MathieuC[MathieuCharacteristicA[\\[Nu], q], q, z], {z, 0, 2 Pi}], 32], {y, 0, 8, 2}, {\\[Nu], 6, 14, 2}]]] /. Complex[r_, i_] :> Chop[Complex[r, i]] finds your total with no warning or error messages. Check that carefully.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes it is just a matter of adjusting the options. Here is a modification of your code that gives an answer fairly quickly and without any messages, using `NIntegrate` and some of its options:

```
P = 0;
l = 0;
x = 4;
κ = 0.01`20; (* note increased precision *)
n = 5;
q = (κ*n)/2;

Do[Q = Exp[((-I)*(MathieuCharacteristicA[ν, q] - x^2/4)*τ/2)]*
       NIntegrate[
        Exp[(-I)*(l - x/2)*θ]*Exp[I*ν*θ]*
        MathieuC[MathieuCharacteristicA[ν, q], q, θ],
        {θ, 0, 2 π},
        WorkingPrecision -> 20
       ]*
       NIntegrate[
        Exp[I*(y - x/2)*z]*Exp[(-I)*ν*z]*
        MathieuC[MathieuCharacteristicA[ν, q], q, z],
        {z, 0, 2 π},
        WorkingPrecision -> 20,
        Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", Method -> "ClenshawCurtisOscillatoryRule"}
       ];
  P = P + Q, 
  {y, 0, 8, 2}, {ν, 6, 14, 2}
];

Q1 = P
```

I will not copy its result here, since you can easily run it for yourself. Although it gives an output without any complaints, what I cannot tell you is whether that result is anything like correct given other trouble observed with `MathieuC` under [similar circumstances](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/83032/is-mathieuc-for-moderately-large-imaginary-arguments-broken). Hopefully you will be able to tell whether or not the answer it provides is what you expected.

Comment: Its not correct because i have to further increase value of y in even integars 
and value of k will also be changed then it again gives error.

Comment: @AmratButt well, you will forgive me for not updating the answer if you don't say what the messages were, how large `y` you are interested in, or how `κ` is supposed to be changed. I will just note that I was able to go up to (at least) `y = 16` with no messages by further adjusting the options. Please tell me that you did not just post your comment here at the first sign of trouble without having investigated other options settings yourself?

Comment: k can vary from 0.01 to 1000 and values of y can go up to infinity because its sum
But why its giving error i couldnot understand this thing

Comment: thanks for the cooperation and our help @Olesksandr R.