# Bad behavior of Mathieu functions in the limit of q-> infinity

Tags: special-functions

I have been playing around with Mathematica's Mathieu functions as I am interested in the their limit when q tends to infinity. In particular I have been plotting several asymptotic forms, the most clearly presented of which I have found to be those outlined in the work of Frenkel and Portugal http://www.lncc.br/~portugal/Mathieu.pdf

```
r = 36; 
q = 5000;
Rasterize[ Plot[{Sqrt[1/\[Pi]]MathieuC[MathieuCharacteristicA[r, q],
 q, z/2 + \[Pi]/2]/Sign[MathieuC[MathieuCharacteristicA[r, q], q, 
\[Pi]/2]], (-1)^(r/2) Sqrt[q^(1/4)/(Sqrt[2 \[Pi]]
r!)] ParabolicCylinderD[r, 2 q^(1/4) Sin[z/2]] }, 
{z, -8 \[Pi]/q^(1/4), 8 \[Pi]/q^(1/4)}, PlotRange -> Full, 
PlotStyle -> {{Blue, Dashed}, {Orange, Dotted}}, 
PlotLegends -> "Expressions", ImageSize -> Large] 
Sign[MathieuC[MathieuCharacteristicA[r, q], q, \[Pi]/2]] Clear[r, q]
```

In particular I would like to point out equation (42) which I have included a comparison of [image: Failure of the Mathieu function at large q for r=6 and q=10^9]

Note that the qualitative features of the Mathieu equation are butchered. Namely the solution plotted has 4 nodes, rather than 6. This happens right around q=10^9 for some reason. At a lower value of q=10^8 you can see everything works perfectly.

[image: Good agreement between asymptotics and Mathematica's "exact" Mathieu function]

Comment: You need to post the executable Mathematica code in code blocks so that it can be copied and pasted into a notebook.

Comment: Please read the description of the [tag:bugs] tag.

Comment: There are several problems with Mathematica's Mathieu functions reported [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=Mathieu) and on stackoverflow.

Comment: @MichaelE2. In particular, it is likely that this is the same error as in [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/83032/is-mathieuc-for-moderately-large-imaginary-arguments-broken).

Comment: Check individual values rather than a plot.  I don't get the same plot as yours, but when I evaluate your expression  I match the expected values.  I assume the difference is because plotting must convert from exact precision, whereas your expression is properly using exact values.